# python recursion for child parent grandparent etc hierarchy

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I am trying to create the full hierarchy chain for every child. I have two dicts, the first contains all child-parent pairs to be used as lookup, and the second contains all children as keys, and their values starts off as a list containing the immediate parent where then the grand parents, great garnd parents etc will be appended to. For simplicity sake, a child cannot have more than one parent, but a parent can have multiple children.

```py
c_p = { "A":"C","B":"C","C":"F","D":"E","E":"F","F":""}
hierarchy = {
    "A": ["C"],
    "B": ["C"],
    "C": ["F"],
    "D": ["E"],
    "E": ["F"],
    "F": [""]
}
expected_result = {
    "A": ["C", "F"],
    "B": ["C", "F"],
    "C": ["F"],
    "D": ["E", "F"],
    "E": ["F"],
    "F": [""],
}
```

Below is the function I have thus far, but it is returning 'str' object has no attribute 'copy'. I know this is because the function is expecting a dict but it is passing through a string but I am not clear on how to structure this function.

```
def hierarchy_gen(data):
    for k, v in data.copy().items():
        last_parent = v[-1]
        if last_parent not in ['F','',None]: 
            v += hierarchy_gen(c_p[last_parent])
        else:
            v += ''
            continue
    return data
test = hierarchy_gen(hierarchy)
```

Comment: Why are you using `.copy()` at all? You don't need to make any copies.

Comment: fair enough, but issue is still the same (i.e, 'str' object has no attribute 'items')

Comment: Error seems pretty self-evident. You're hitting the base case, a string, and so you can't call `.items()` or `.copy()` on that. That said, I'm not really sure how to interpret your input structures. Are you supposed to convert `'3'` to an integer `3` to find its children? What are the rules here? What's up with that `10` that disappeared in the output? `c_p` and `hierarchy` seem to contain more or less the same information, random string/int conversions aside.

Comment: @ggorlen these are types, I have updated the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some terminology. We're doing a transitive closure over a forest (a data structure containing the roots of many trees). By denoting the structure as a forest, I'm assuming there are no cycles in the graph.

```py
def transitive_closure(forest):
    def recurse(root, path):
        if root in forest and forest[root]:
            for x in forest[root]:
                path.append(root)
                recurse(x, path)
                path.pop()
        elif path:
            result[path[0]] = path[1:]

    result = {}

    for root in forest:
        recurse(root, [])

    return result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    hierarchy = {
        "A": ["C"],
        "B": ["C"],
        "C": ["F"],
        "D": ["E"],
        "E": ["F"],
        "F": [""]
    }
    print(transitive_closure(hierarchy))
```

Now, there's some inconsistency in the expected output. Either `""` counts as a node value or it doesn't. If we count it, you can use

```py
result[path[0]] = path[1:] + [root]
```

but then you'll see `""` at the end of every closure path because `"F": [""]` is the terminal point of everything in this particular forest. Or maybe you meant to use `"F": []` to indicate that `"F"` has no children, in which case you'll still want to append the current node to the path on the base case. You could also handle this as a special value, but that strikes me as a poor design.

Additionally, `c_p` seems totally pointless since `hierarchy` contains the exact same information, with lists as values. I assume it's possible that some elements have more than a single child, otherwise it's a pretty dull data structure. As it stands, the example is basically a linked list, a degenerate tree.